# Curl copy command in PHP

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to copy

```
curl -c cookie_jar -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"username" : "admin", "password" : "admin"}' http://jira:8080/rest/auth/latest/session
```

in PHP but I cannot seem to get it working.

I have

```
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_URL, $loginUrl );
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '{"username" : "admin", "password" : "admin"}');
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, '/tmp/cookiejar' );
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADERS,array('Content-Type: application/json')); 
curl_exec( $curl );
```

Any help?

Comment: It would help a lot (and maybe even solve the problem) if you could post the HTTP requests generated by the two calls (You can use [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) for capturing them)

Comment: True, it would but its a remote linux server without root capabilities. Is there a method if displaying what the final resulting curl command is in php?

Comment: If your machine is accessible from this remote server, you can maybe set the target url to your own machine IP, and see these requests arrive instead of see them leave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually need the CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE option, actually. COOKIEJAR species where to write new cookies to. COOKIEFILE is for loading existing cookies into CURL. Your PHP equivalent right now is not sending any cookies - it's only recording them. Add this, and you should be good to go:

```
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, '/tmp/cookiejar' );
                                ^^^^---the big difference.
```